# Algorithm for optimal allocation of batches to processors with variable speeds

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking for a similar problem to the combinatorial problem I describe below. I'd like to adapt the solution to the existing problem to mine.

The problem:
Suppose you have:

- A process $P_1$ that produces one batch *b* per day on 5 days of a 7 day week. Say days 1-5.
- A process $P_2$ that takes the batches, the $b$'s, and processes them in chambers $c_{16},...c_{26}$. Each chamber can take one batch at a time and it takes $n$ days for that chamber to process the batch, where $n=$the subscript of that chamber. So, for example, $c_{18}$ needs 18 days to process the batch.
- This combination of processes $P_1$ and $P_2$ runs indefinitely.

The objective function:
minimize the average number of $K$ batches that finish processing on the same day in $P_2$, where $K\ge365$

Comment: Does each batch need to be processed in each of the ten chambers (so the minimum total production time for a single batch is $1+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 56$ days)? If in just one chamber, there are many solutions for $K = 5/7$ with a 7-day cycle; for example, by using the chambers $c_6$, $c_3$, $c_5$, $c_2$, and $c_4$ for the five consecutive days a batch is produced, so that on five days out of seven, one batch is completed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Nominal Animal, I realize now that in simplifying the problem, I made it a bit too easy to solve, so that a solution is not helpful. I've update the batch processing times to make them longer than the number of days in a week (my current situtation).

Comment: Unfortunately, the rate at which $P_2$ can produce batches is now $\sum_{i=16}^{26} 1/i = 14354439271/26771144400 \approx 0.53619$ [batches per day] which is smaller than the rate at which $P_1$ produces batches, $5/7 \approx 0.71429$ [batches per day]. You need to increase the number of chambers to 17 ($c_{16}$ to $c_{32}$, inclusive) for $P_2$ to match or exceed the production rate of $P_1$. When the exact numbers are known, I'd just use a small program to find an optimal solution (if one exists) numerically.

Comment: Thank you very much @NominalAnimal. I will continue to focus on computer solution then, unless I hear from another person.

Comment: I do suspect, from looking at a couple of different cases, that *if* $P_2$ had a greater total rate of production than $P_1$, and the $P_2$ chambers' processing times are a complete sequence, the solution is also a simple sequence (just consider 6-3-5-2-4, for example). Maybe consider the case where $P_1$ produces a batch every day, and try such structured sequences to try and find the rule for the $P_2$ sequence?